# Is it ok to hide a "Developer mode" in my app?

Tags: user-interface

I have an mobile app. While in debug, I need to test several different stuff, so I created a button that shows a list of these tests.

Even in Release, some things are different (Apple Push Notification). So I need to test in release too.

Is it ok to leave these shortcuts hidden when releasing the app?

Comment: Please don't rollback the tag removal, as explained before, `hidden-features` tag is blacklisted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing so would leave a massive security hole in your application, which should be avoided **at all costs**. In fact, if you're creating an iOS app, I doubt such a hole would get by Apple's independent release testing.

Ideally, you should be using separate coding environments for development, testing and production. When you're developing, you should be using one of the various simulators to test as you work. There's an in-built one in XCode that can simulate a variety of Apple devices, and if you're using something like Ionic, you can hook it to a live preview in a web browser.

Once you're happy that things are working on your computer, you then should be deploying a *development* .ipa / .apk file. This file should only be released 'in-house', manually. If that's all good, you move on to testing. For testing, create a secondary file, and this can be distributed for external testing through something like **[Apple TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)**.

For production, you'd remove **any** 'backdoors', as in theory, your app would be ready for the **public**. At this stage it's a simple matter of releasing it through either the Google Play Store or Apple Store.

Comment: These tests aren't potencial backdoors. Only connection tests and info about the app. Nothing that the user can exploit and do what he shouldn't.

Comment: btw the app is being developed in Xamarin.Forms (Android and iOS)

Comment: Even so, you won't want to display that sort of information. It's extraneous for production, and you never know how it might be used :)

Comment: I thought that too, but that would be useful for support. Should I create a page just for this?

Comment: Well I'm not too sure on the overall intended functionality of your app, but in *general* you'd just have a link to customer support. Like a button that submits diagnostic information about the app. If you mean support with testing, you should be clearly telling your testers what to look for and do *outside* of the app.

Comment: Without knowing what sort of information the developer mode exposes, you simply cannot make a blanket statement that this would "leave a massive security hole".